# Show that if $\sigma^2 = \varepsilon$, then $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint transpositions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

The full exercise is

> If $\sigma \in S_n$, show that $\sigma^2=\varepsilon$ if and only if $\sigma$ is the product of disjoint transpositions.

The forward part is easy, but I'm not sure about the backwards statement. How does $\sigma^2 = \varepsilon$ imply that its transpositions are all disjoint? I don't want the full answer, just a hint. (And by hint I don't mean "do the whole thing and leave the last step as a hint", I would like the least help possible so I can still challenge myself in this exercise)

The definition of two disjoint permutations is that no element is moved by both. The closest result that I know of would be the cycle decomposition theorem, which states that

> If $\sigma \neq \varepsilon$ is a permutation in $S_n$, then $\sigma$ is a product of (one or more) **disjoint** cycles of length at least 2. This factorization is unique up to the order of the cycles.

From here, would I just need to somehow show that each factor is a transposition? This is where I got stuck, so a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you square a product of disjoint cycles

Comment: Using the cycle decomposition theorem is the right idea.  What’s the alternative to $\sigma$ being a product of disjoint transpositions?

Answer (score 1):

Write your permutation as the product of disjoint cycles. The permutation squared is on one hand the identity and on the other is the product of each cycle squared. Therefore, each cycle has order $2$, and is thus a transposition. Here we only use that squaring “distributes” across the cycle structure of a permutation.

Answer (score 0):

Transpositions have order $2$, disjoint cycles commute, and the order of a permutation written in disjoint cycle form is the $\text{lcm}$ of the lengths of the cycles...